# How to capture / digitise a live satellite stream

Tags: video-capture

I have coordinates, descrambling codes, et al for a live satellite broadcast.  I'm looking to capture that feed into a digital stream that I can feed into AWS's Video services.

My experience is software side - once the stream is digital I'm good. I'm wondering what kind of equipment / hardware is needed to tune to and capture that satellite feed? Are there companies that offer this as a service? Is this a dumb question?

Thanks!

*Adding Some more context based on questions in the comments*

**Is the feed on a LEO, MEO, or GEO satellite? If it is GEO, which satellite and transponder?**

It is GEO. Azerspace-1 / Azercosmos 46degrees East.  Not exactly sure what transponder but I think its C-band. Does that make sense? I have frequency ranges for Bandwidth,  U/L and D/L.

**What is your budget?**

TBD - Part of this exercise is determining costs to capture the feed.

**When you say "once the stream is digital" what exactly do you mean? Once you have an MPEG TS or something else?**

Exactly that - I'm looking to get an MPEG TS that I can plug into AWS services like https://www.elemental.com/products/aws-elemental-live

Comment: Welcome! Is the feed on a LEO, MEO, or GEO satellite? If it is GEO, which satellite and transponder? What is your budget? When you say "once the stream is digital" what exactly do you mean? Once you have an MPEG TS or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the poignant questions @MichaelLiebman - I've edited my original post to add more clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like most of the content on [Azerspace-1](https://www.lyngsat.com/AzerSpace-1-Africasat-1a.html) is "in the clear", or not encrypted, which makes things easier. But there is still a lot of "it depends" for exactly what equipment you need. Aside from all of the earth station equipment (dish, [LNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-noise_amplifier), down converter, etc.), you will need a DVB-S2 or MPEG-4 receiver. That could be a vanilla receiver with an external encapsulator or gateway.

There are definitely companies that provide teleport and satellite media services. I'm not familiar with Azerspace-1's footprint to give concrete recommendations. However, two examples of companies that might be appropriate are [Intelsat](http://www.intelsat.com/global-network/intelsatone/teleports/) (Fuchsstadt teleport) and [Encompass](https://www.encompass.tv/encompass-riga/).